# Can I use an HVLP sprayer on the exterior of my house?

Tags: painting, paint

I’m painting the outside of my house. Wood siding. I’m using a brush and roller but I remembered I have an hvlp paint sprayer that I think would be pretty convenient to use. I was reading online that I shouldn’t use hvlp for painting a house. But it didn’t say why. Does anybody know?

Here’s the article that says not to do it. 
http://www.house-painting-info.com/articles/hvlp/#.WwZDaaJlDYU

I could use an airless sprayer but there is a ton of prep work in that because of the over spray and the hvlp is a bit more manageable in the overspray department.

Also I just want to try it out. But not if it won’t apply the paint correctly or something.

Also the house is small. 950 square feet.

Comment: seems like the complaint may be about refilling the reservoir too often ..... http://www.hotrodders.com/forum/hvlp-can-i-paint-my-house-140720.html

Comment: I've used an HVLP sprayer to paint the outside of a 2200sqft house. Worked great - no problems at all. The only minor issue was refilling the reservoir regularly.

Comment: They're probably concerned with wind.  You should be concerned with overspray. You're thinking "less" overspray means "less" masking. 
Masking  doesn't work that way.